# Jquery move every third row (before dom-manipulation) up one row

Tags: jquery, css, dom-manipulation

I have a table which I want to reorganize. The table looks like this:

```html
    <table border=1>
     <tr>
      <td>image 1</td>
      <td>image 2</td>
      <td>image 3</td>
      <td>image 4</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>text 1</td>
      <td>text 2</td>
      <td>text 3</td>
      <td>text 4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>image 5</td>
      <td>image 6</td>
      <td>image 7</td>
      <td>image 8</td>
     </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>text 5</td>
       <td>text 6</td>
      <td>text 7</td>
      <td>text 8</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

And I want this to be my end result:

```html
 <table border=1>
     <tr>
      <td>image 1</td>
      <td>image 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>text 1</td>
      <td>text 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>image 3</td>
      <td>image 4</td>                
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>text 3</td>
      <td>text 4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>image 5</td>
      <td>image 6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>text 5</td>
      <td>text 6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>image 7</td>
      <td>image 8</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>text 7</td>
      <td>text 8</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

I figured out how to move the cells to a new row:

```
$('table tr').each(function(e)
{
    $('<tr>').insertAfter(this).append($('>:gt(1)',this));
});
```

But then I want to move every third row to every second row. This code will move every third row after manipulation, but I need it to take every third row before the manipulation:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(3n)').each(function(e)
{     
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());    
});
```

How can I achieve that? And is there a better way? I tried doing it while making the rows, but that didn't work either. I have a fiddle right here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2vd5kzq6/40/

I want to do this to make the table a lot more mobile friendlier. So if anybody knows a solution that works in CSS it would be even better, but I figured there's to much manipulation going on for CSS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [See this](http://jsfiddle.net/Hskke/143/) - it will swap columns/rows for you,/may help

Comment: Is this actually tabular layout, or are you using tables for layout?

Comment: I'm definitely not using tables for the layout ;)

Comment: So this is, in fact, tabular data you're using? And Not "image + captions" (which, BTW, could be done more effectively *without* tables)?

Comment: Yeas, these text and image lines are pure for example purposes because I cannot show the real data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your own solution was nearly complete. you made only one mistake.

you don't want to swap every third row, but every 4th -1 row!
to visualize it: you selected row 3,6,9 ... but you need 3,7,11 ...

therefore, just take your code and add a prev():

```
$('table tr:nth-child(4n)').prev().each(function(e)
{     
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());    
});
```

see the result over here: http://jsfiddle.net/2vd5kzq6/41/

Comment: If people are interested to know how to 'undo' this action, I created a fiddle for that here: http://jsfiddle.net/2vd5kzq6/50/